Update a table with a rank number with a subquery
I am using the following SQL query to update a temp table to be able to determine priority.
This is my SQL statement
UPDATE #CARD
SET rank_no = x.no_rank
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         rank_no, chg_tot_amt, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by pt_id ORDER BY [chg_tot_amt]) AS no_rank
     FROM 
         #CARD x 
     WHERE 
         noproc = 2) x
WHERE
    x.no_rank IS NOT NULL

This is the result I get:
pt_id   rank_no  chg_tot_amt    no_rank
--------------------------------------
99999990    1      4722.3         1
99999990    1     17712.6         2
99999991    1     13643.26        1
99999991    1     15851.24        2
99999992    1      3814.94        1
99999992    1     18033.78        2
99999993    1     18033.78        1
99999993    1     19915.28        2
99999994    1      3814.94        1
99999994    1     15851.24        2
99999995    1      3814.94        1
99999995    1     15851.24        2
99999996    1     13643.26        1
99999996    1     15851.24        2

This statement is updating the rank_no as 1 instead of 1,2 or 3 as expected.

You probably need: UPDATE x... instead of UPDATE #CARD.... Also, where x.no_rank is not null is pointless, row number cannot be null

It looks like you only have, at most, 2 rows of each pt_id. If that's true then how do you expect to see an rank higher than 2? If none of the answers given help, please show some sample input data and the expected results.

There is no join condition on your subquery.
With join condition:
UPDATE c
SET c.rank_no = x.no_rank
FROM #CARD c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        pt_id, chg_tot_amt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pt_id ORDER BY chg_tot_amt) AS no_rank
    FROM #CARD
    WHERE noproc = 2
   ) x ON c.pt_id = r.pt_id AND c.chg_tot_amt = x.chg_tot_amt
WHERE x.no_rank IS NOT NULL

Output:



pt_id
rank_no
chg_tot_amt




99999990
1
4722.30


99999990
2
17712.60


99999991
1
13643.26


99999991
2
15851.24


99999992
1
3814.94


99999992
2
18033.78


99999993
1
18033.78


99999993
2
19915.28


99999994
1
3814.94


99999994
2
15851.24


99999995
1
3814.94


99999995
2
15851.24


99999996
1
13643.26


99999996
2
15851.24



fiddle

You can update the derived row-numbering table directly, you don't need a join anyway.
UPDATE x
SET rank_no = x.no_rank
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by c.pt_id ORDER BY c.chg_tot_amt) AS no_rank
    FROM #CARD c
    where c.noproc =2
) x;

